# Call to wait() inside the run() method of a Thread

Tags: java

I'm curious about why this doesn't work? I'm getting an IllegalMonitorStateException. This is the run method for a Runnable that has been encapsulated in a Thread and started.

```
public void run()
{
    while(true)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World"); 

        synchronized(Thread.currentThread())
        {
            try{
                wait();     
            }  
            catch (InterruptedException e){}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The [IllegalMonitorStateException API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalMonitorStateException.html) and the [Object API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()) both have useful information on this. Have you read these? If not, please do so. If so, what about the information shown there confuses you?

Comment: Also, please check out this excellent article on Java Threads and monitors: [Chapter 20 of Inside the Java Virtual Machine
Thread Synchronization](http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/threadsynch.html)

Comment: I realized it right before checking and fixed it. My mistake. Thanks for the resources, I'll be sure to look at them!

Answer (score 8):

You are calling `wait()` on one object (the `Runnable`) while owning the monitor of another object (the result of `Thread.currentThread()`). You must own the monitor (`synchronize` on) the *same* object that you call `wait()` on. So this would not result in an the error:

```
public void run() {
    synchronized(this) {
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As per javadoc for [wait()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29):

```
IllegalMonitorStateException - if the current thread is not the owner of the object's monitor.
```

When you call wait(), you are invoking it on the Runnable instance. Since your synchronized block is on the current thread and not on `this`, you do not hold the lock for the current instance. You should change your code to `synchronized(this)` to avoid the exception.